# Hypothesis at 5% significant for slope and intercept coefficient

Tags: hypothesis-testing, regression-coefficients, intercept

"Conduct hypotheses tests at a 5% significance level on the intercept and slope coefficient to see if the intercept is significantly different from zero and the slope coefficient is significantly different from one "

Does this mean i have 2 different hypotheses tests, or 1 that compares both? As i've carried out a hypothesis on the slope coefficient

```
Null: H0: β1 = 0 at  = 0.05
Alt: H1: β1 ≠ 0 at  = 0.05
Test-stat = 5.309772708
Critical value = maybe 2.042
T is smaller Than C so Reject H0
```

Any pointers on this would be great as im trying to pick up the basics but am stuck on this part of my online course

Comment: The question indeed is ambiguous and could mean either one of your interpretations.  If your answer will be used to evaluate your performance in a course or job, then consider responding to both interpretations.  The use of plural in "hypotheses tests" suggests two tests are requested--but that still leaves open the question whether the "5% level" should be applied to each test separately or to the combined result.

Comment: Yes, i'm thinking its two different tests, both with a 5% significant test. But i shall play it safe and try do it both ways as suggested